# the custom drop down in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I used a custom drop-down in my project with a text button and search box in the drop-down now the case is that filter search is not working means it not displaying on the drop-down but in the console, I can see the item that I search in the box so I want help for that so apply search in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [DropdownSearch package on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search), it might be of help to you.

Or rather provide the code in a way we will understand so that we can suggest changes.